# Kubernetes Admin not showing pods accordingly

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

[image]

Refer to the image above, I'm using minikube and it took about 10 minutes to show up when the pod running as below. Anyone knows how to get this display upon services running?

```
[root@localhost /]# kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
meow-799b895f78-htgws   1/1     Running   0          25m
meow-799b895f78-wktmn   1/1     Running   0          25m
[root@localhost /]#
```

apart of that, any other stable virtual box equal to minikube? It spent me a lot of time by keep on restarting or reinstalling the clusters to get simple things up.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu, you may want to check out microk8s.  Installed using snapd.  https://microk8s.io. no vm required.  Bootstrapping is faster.  Utilizing snap to isolate file system.  Afaik, snap is also available on other distros. Snap is available by default on 18.04 ubuntu btw.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is opinion based, but I think minikube is working pretty well and stable. I had no bigger problems with it on Ubuntu and I used it for many different tests.

About your question, minikube VM is configured to use 1 GB of RAM and 1 CPU by default. You can change it. Delete the cluster - `minikube delete` and then run it again with 
for example:
`minikube start --memory 8192 --cpus 4`
The long time of waiting may be also caused by your network connection, as before the pod is started the image has to be downloaded.

About the alternatives you can also try [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Comment: i am using centos, its able to use run properly after 40 minutes boot up for first time. The logs showing it's started but the admin page is not showing up yet but after 15 minutes it's able to load. Any command to see whether it's 100% loaded?

Comment: what do you mean by 100% loaded, you can see that with `kubectl get pods -w` while in pending state it is still running. What exactly is your issue now? Did you try to run minikube with higher amount of resources?